# What is the SEO impact of using an anchor tag without a href attribute?

Tags: seo, links

For better user experience, all top level items in the primary menu are set to an empty href so that they only serve as labels for navigation menu sections. They cannot be clicked on and lead nowhere not even href="#". Below is an example:

Category Menu - (Parent menu item that is set to `<a>Categories Menu</a>`)

Category 1 - (Sub Menu Link) - `<a href="http://domain.com/category/category-1/">Category 1</a>`

Category 2 - (Sub Menu Link) - `<a href="http://domain.com/category/category-2/">Category 2</a>`

I am working on a site that has a particular structure and I just want to know if its worth changing it or if its OK to keep as is. How will this structure effect SEO in terms of passing link juice and ranking?

Comment: Why not use a heading because, you know, it's a heading?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to gain some sort of SEO advantage with bogus links, I do not see the point. Fake or real, the result, if you are getting away with something, would be exactly the same. Just make some real links.

Comment: I am not trying to take advantage of fake links. I am working on a site that has a particular structure and I just want to know if its worth changing it or if its OK to keep as is.

Comment: or it could be because he doesn't know how to use a element other than `<a>` in the template he/she is using...

Comment: Use `<li>Menu Label</li>` without using `<a>` if you want the same appearance then copy the appearance from `ul li a{}` into `ul li{}`

Comment: Okay. Are you saying these links exist now? And you are wondering if it is a good idea to change or remove the dead links? If that is the case, then Heck Yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an accepted usage of anchor tags without href attributes: Named anchors such as:

```
<a name=sectionA>Section A</a>
```

Search engines are fine with that, so they should be fine with your `a` tag with no attributes as well.  They won't see it as a link and they won't try to pass link juice to it.